extra dot printed after email addresses in latex
I am trying to print one affiliation for the authors of a paper in latex. However, an extra dot is printed after the email addresses and I don't know how to get rid of it. Here is the code:
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical 
%\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
%%%%
\usepackage{lmodern}

% number format
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[square, numbers]{natbib}%
\addbibresource{sn-bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
%\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

%\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

%\title[Article Title]{Article Title}
\author*[1]{\fnm{E***} \sur{B***}}
\author[1]{\fnm{S****} \sur{A***}}
\author[1]{\fnm{A****} \sur{S****}}
\author[1]{\fnm{H****} \sur{A****}}
\author[1]{\fnm{K****} \sur{K****}}
\affil{
$^{1}$School of Computer Science, The University of **** \\
\href{}{ {\{firstemail, secondemail, thirdemail, fourthemail, fifthemail\}}@test.edu}
}

\title[Article Title]{A Survey On Recent methods for }
\end{document}


Actually, if you follow the class guidelines, a semicolon is added.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{A Survey On Recent methods for}
\author[1]{\fnm{E***} \sur{B***}}
\author[1]{\fnm{S****} \sur{A***}}
\author[1]{\fnm{A****} \sur{S****}}
\author[1]{\fnm{H****} \sur{A****}}
\author[1]{\fnm{K****} \sur{K****}}
\email{{\{firstemail, secondemail, thirdemail, fourthemail, fifthemail\}}@test.edu}

\affil[1]{%
  \orgdiv{Some Department},
  \orgname{Some University}%
  % ... other data
}
\maketitle

\end{document}


Apparently, that's what they want.
A cure.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% fix some strange ideas of the class
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\email}{m}
 {
  \global\advance\emailcnt by 1\relax
  \legacy_if:nTF { @corauemail }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_snjnl_corrauthemail_seq
     {
      \setcounter{footnote}{0}
      \textcolor{blue}{#1}
     }
   }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_snjnl_authemail_seq
     {
      \setcounter{footnote}{0}
      \textcolor{blue}{#1}
     }
   }
 }
\seq_new:N \g_snjnl_corrauthemail_seq
\seq_new:N \g_snjnl_authemail_seq
\AddToHook{cmd/@maketitle/before}
 {
  \tl_set:Ne \corrauthemail { \seq_use:Nn \g_snjnl_corrauthemail_seq {;~}}
  \tl_set:Ne \authemail { \seq_use:Nn \g_snjnl_authemail_seq {;~}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{A Survey On Recent methods for}
\author*[1]{\fnm{E***} \sur{B***}}
\author[1]{\fnm{S****} \sur{A***}}
\author[1]{\fnm{A****} \sur{S****}}
\author[1]{\fnm{H****} \sur{A****}}
\author[1]{\fnm{K****} \sur{K****}}
\email{{\{firstemail, secondemail, thirdemail, fourthemail, fifthemail\}}@test.edu}

\affil[1]{%
  \orgdiv{Some Department},
  \orgname{Some University}%
  % ... other data
}
\maketitle

\end{document}



Thank you for your response. It gives me error (= must be inside math mode) on these two lines:
\seq_new:N \g_snjnl_corrauthemail_seq
\seq_new:N \g_snjnl_authemail_seq
Can you help please? It did not produce any pdf as a result

@Elika You possibly didn’t copy the whole code.

thanks for your prompt. I did. I even opened a new blank project and copied everything but it doesn't produce and pdf and here is the error: LaTeX Error: File `sn-jnl.cls' not found.

@Elika You need to stay in the folder where the class file is.

Also, how can I delete that "contributing authors" before the email addresses? I want the email addresses to be i9n simple format just like "some university"

@Elika If you're required to use sn-jnl, leave everything as they want.
